# Deploy project created with foundation-cli?

Tags: deployment, zurb-foundation, github-pages

I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to deploy this project  https://github.com/nataliecardot/zeus-hosting-setup, preferably to GitHub Pages. No dist folder is created when I run `foundation build`, which apparently is [an old issue](https://github.com/foundation/foundation-cli/issues/97). Is it possible for my to deploy this in any way? Or if not, any other way to get it online?

Comment: I will check the project setup and provide a PR.

Comment: I ended up copying the static/minified files into another repo (https://github.com/nataliecardot/zeus-hosting) and published to GitHub Pages without issue. Still very odd it seems there isn't a way to deploy using the foundation-cli version.

Comment: Did you already try `foundation build`?

Comment: Yes I tried that a few times

Comment: I will check what's gone wrong.

Comment: Hi, the `build` command builds only the css, the js is already there and can be used as is. See https://github.com/DanielRuf/foundation-cli-dist-test/runs/260245940#step:6:24

Comment: But you might want to use a preconfigured setup for your case, see foundation-zurb-template (https://github.com/foundation/foundation-zurb-template) and try it with `foundation new --framework sites --template zurb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate the static pages that will be published online, and do so in the appropriate branch.

Since master includes what is necessary to generate the pages, said pages need to be stored in a `gh_pages` branch.
See "[Types of GitHub Pages sites](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites)" and its next section "[Publishing sources for GitHub Pages sites](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites)".

The point remains: that repository as it is, with only its `master` branch, would not make any page visible on its own.

Comment: I copied the HTML files, referenced JS files, and minified CSS into another repo and it published looking as it did in development. I don't understand why I can't do the same with the original repo, since the same CSS and JS files are referenced.

Comment: @Natalie Maybe because of the addition step suggested by Daniel?

Comment: I'm not sure what additional step you're referring to, the build step transpiles Sass to CSS, and the CSS file output is what's referenced in the HTML. The JavaScript can be used as is so I don't see why there would be a problem with that.