# Why can't I publish my repo to GitHub Pages?

Tags: deployment, zurb-foundation, github-pages

I made a project using Zurb Foundation's cli, located here: https://github.com/nataliecardot/zeus-hosting-setup. I built the files and Sass was transpiled to CSS. For some reason when I tried publishing from the master branch, only the HTML appears (resulting live site [here](http://nataliecardot.com/zeus-hosting-setup/)).

For sites without a special build process (just plain HTML and CSS), I'm always able to set my site to publish from the master branch in the repo's settings under GitHub Pages (although [this link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites) says project repos are published from the gh-pages branch by default, whereas user/organization pages are built from the master branch by default, so I'm not sure why I'm able to do that). For sites that have a build process in place like projects scaffolded with Create React App, I normally use gh-pages package to deploy (I'm not even sure why that's necessary, though), but it didn't work with this project -- I *think* because a dist folder isn't created when I run `foundation build`. I asked about it in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58387177/deploy-project-created-with-foundation-cli/58387404?noredirect=1#comment103147794_58387404) and someone said the build process just creates the CSS file and the JS file can be used as is. (When you run `foundation build` with that repo, it says 'starting Sass .... finished Sass').

My workaround to publish the site was to copy the HTML files as well as the CSS and JS files referenced in the HTML files into [another repo](https://github.com/nataliecardot/zeus-hosting), and I set the website to be published from master. It worked fine.

I don't understand why I can't do the same from the original repo, since the same CSS and JS files referenced by the HTML are in it. What's the difference between the two repos? Is the presence of a node_modules folder/Sass files/a Gulp files in the original repo preventing it from being published to master with the CSS?

Also if anyone knows how I can publish from the original repo I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, what exactly is your question? I guess it is best to discuss these in our issue tracker, Gitter or Slack.

Comment: You might want to use the foundation-zurb-template as this is preconfigured for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node_modules` is ignored at https://github.com/nataliecardot/zeus-hosting-setup/blob/master/.gitignore#L3 because this folder is often huge and should not be uploaded.

Same for the `css` folder, see https://github.com/nataliecardot/zeus-hosting-setup/blob/master/.gitignore#L5

Please try to migrate to the ZURB template which is preconfigured for your use case.

The setup that you have is a basic one which is mainly for development purposes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I was able to get it online using the ZURB template you mentioned (silly mistake using the other one). Deleted my old repos for the project and created a new one. If you (or anyone's) interested I detailed how I published it in the README: https://github.com/nataliecardot/zeus-hosting

Comment: Thanks for the feedback that it is working now. Awesome =)